# Show that if, for some $ψ$, $Γ \vdash ψ$ and $Γ \vdash ¬ψ$, then $Γ \vdash φ$, for any formula $φ$.

Tags: proof-verification, logic

> Show that if, for some $ψ$, $Γ \vdash ψ$ and $Γ \vdash ¬ψ$, then $Γ \vdash φ$, for any formula $φ$. [Hint: Use a result from Exercise 3.7, as attached below.]
>
> [image]

(Could anyone check my proof please? Also would it matter if I use g instead of f? Because while g is a tautology and f isn't, they both look very similar, if not, almost identical.)

Suppose $Γ \vdash ψ$ and $Γ \vdash ¬ψ$, and we have them on $k$ and $k+1$ lines respectively. Then we utilise Ex3.7f to modus ponens and produce $φ$. Since one can substitute $φ$ with any formula, we can - as asked by the question - derive any formula $φ$.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    (k) & ψ & ... \\
    (k+1) & ¬ψ & ... \\
(k+2) & ¬ψ\vdash(ψ\toφ) & 3.7f \\
(k+3) & (ψ\toφ) & (k+1),(k+2) MP \\
(k+4) & φ & k,(k+3) MP \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Looks good to me. If you're wondering, the name of what you proved is the principle of explosion:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion. If you can derive a contradiction, you can derive anything.

Comment: Which inference rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Ispil Thank you! Would it be better if I use g instead of f because the former is a tautology? Or would it make no difference?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Modus ponens is the only rule of inference I am allowed for now

Comment: @DanielMak Either f or g works here, since they are effectively equivalent by virtue of the deduction theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem. I would say that g probably looks cleaner when the only inference rule you have is modus ponens. The proof, though, would be nearly identical.